# PHP how to check for equality of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Well, I have no clue why I'm not able to get a code below to work:

```
    $test1 = array(6500,6537,3013);
    $test2 = array(223,6500);
    if ( in_array( $test1, $test2) ) {
        echo "something is there";
    }
```

I'm trying to get `true` when at least one value from `test1` exists in the array `test2`

Based on an Example #3 from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) it should to work.

Comment: I'd reread Example #3 if I were you to see what it actually is comparing

Comment: Then read the PHP Docs for [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: In context of  Example 3, the entire array $test1 would be a sub-array of $test2.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the behavior you expect?  Currently, the array `$test2` is not an element of `$test1`, so I'm not sure what you're looking for here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [array_intersect()](http://php.net/array_intersect) instead. `in_array` does **NOT** consider arrays in the "needle" as distinct individual values to test for. It tests for the entire array as a whole.

e.g.

```
php > $arr = array(1,2,3,array(4,5));
php > $test1 = array(1,3);
php > $test2 = array(4,5);

php > var_dump(in_array($test1, $arr));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(in_array($test2, $arr));
bool(true)

php > var_dump(array_intersect($test1, $arr));
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in php shell code on line 1
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in php shell code on line 1
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array
>   it is worth to know that in_array checks against exact value (regarding its data type).

in your example, your conditional will never return true.

consider examples below:

```
php > $t1 = array(6500, 6537, 3013);
php > $t2 = array(223, 6500);
```

does [223, 6500] include [6500, 6537, 3013]? ofcourse no.

```
php > echo in_array($t1, $t2) ? "something is here" : "nihil";
nihil
php > $x = 223;
```

does [223, 6500] include 223? yes. so, it will print "something is here".

```
php > echo in_array($x, $t2) ? "something is here" : "nihil";
something is here

php > $t1 = array(6500, 6537, 3013, 223);
```

does array [6500, 6537, 3013, 223] includes **array [223, 6500]**?
again no.

```
php > echo in_array($t2, $t1) ? "something is here" : "nihil";
nihil
php > $t1 = array(223, 6500, 6537, 3013);
```

nothing will change if we insert 223 as first (zeroth) element.
there is  not an [223, 6500] array inside [223, 6500, 6537, 3013] array.

```
php > echo in_array($t2, $t1) ? "something is here" : "nihil";
nihil
```

[[223, 6500], 6537, 3013] includes [223, 6500].

```
php > $t1 = array(array(223, 6500), 6537, 3013);
php > echo in_array($t2, $t1) ? "something is here" : "nihil";
something is here
```